# Calling functions inside Vue.js template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My template:

```
<template id="players-template" inline-template>
        <div v-for="player in players">
            <div v-bind:class="{ 'row': ($index + 1) % 3 == 0 }">
                <div class="player col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                <a href="#">{{ player.username }}</a>
                                <span class="small pull-right">{{ player.createdAt }}</span>
                            </h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <img v-bind:src="player.avatar" alt="{{ player.username }}" class="img-circle center-block">
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success send-message" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Wyślij wiadomość" v-bind:id="player.id" @click="createConversation(player.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>&nbsp;</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Pokaż profil"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Zobacz szczegółowe informacje o poście"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>&nbsp;</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

My script:

```
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    methods: {
        createConversation: function(id) { 
            console.log("createConversation()");
            console.log(id);
        }
    }
});
```

When the template is rendering i gets an error `[Vue warn]: v-on:click="createConversation" expects a function value, got undefined`. I don't know how to use methods inside a component template. If someone could help me I would appreciate is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need the createConversation method to be on the global Vue instance, you should look at [dispatching events](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Custom_Events). Your component should like this:

```
Vue.component('playersTemplate', {
  template: '#players-template',
  methods: {
    createConversation: function (id) {
        this.$dispatch('createConversation', id)
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The global Vue instance should implement the createConversation event, instead of a method:

```
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    events: {
        createConversation: function(id) { 
            console.log("createConversation()");
            console.log(id);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method should be in the component, not in your global Vue instance.  All functions are called as `this.createConversation` behind the scenes, so it needs to be within the component that is the template for.

Comment: I don't want this function in that component because it does something completely different. Template gets the users from database and show them. Then I want to create new conversation when I click on the button.

Comment: You can use events like in the other answer, or you can always access the root Vue instance using `this.$root`.  So on your click event you could use `$root.createConversation(player.id)`.  I'd encourage you to try to structure your components so each component manages its own functionality, this is the best for re-usability and a core concept of Vue.

Comment: I want to structure my app. That's why I don't want to mix different functionality.

Comment: Just for kicks and giggles, there is such a thing as over compensating components. Each component being responsible for its own functionality is one thing, but some things other components should control otherwise you're retreating back to spaghetti coding where each process is its own little app.

also, what if two component require virtually the same processing? you're going to code the same process twice with its own little variations because they're in different components? Thats a recipe for a maintenance nightmare